# Is it possible to compile minted under Emacs?

Tags: packages, emacs, minted

I am trying to use minted package... Here is an example `minimal.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
4
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I need to run `pdflatex -shell-escape minimal` in a terminal to compile it... When I try to compile it within Emacs as a usual tex file by `C-c C-c`, I got an error: `Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag`. Could anyone tell me where I could add this `-shell-escape flag` under Emacs?

Another small question is regarding `minted.sty`, at the moment I put it in the same folder as the tex files, which is not the best way I guess... Where do you often put `.sty` files?

Comment: Both [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org) and [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) are shipped with a package manager that allows for easy install of packages to the appropriate location (this includes updating the FNDB). For adding the `-shell-escape` Emacs, does [Customizing pdfLaTeX for a particular file with AUCTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12243/customizing-pdflatex-for-a-particular-file-with-auctex) or [Using minted (source code LaTeX package) with emacs/auctex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300497/using-minted-source-code-latex-package-with-emacs-auctex) help?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12243/customizing-pdflatex-for-a-particular-file-with-auctex http://old.nabble.com/shell-escape-td1076639.html http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-02/msg00912.html

Comment: You could instead compile with latexmk (which is better in other ways too) in emacs and set it to use shell-escape in it's configuration file, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587287/how-do-i-bind-latexmk-to-one-key-in-emacs-and-have-it-show-errors-if-there-are-a

Comment: About where to put the `.sty` files. Ideally, this package would be included in your distribution. If not, you would normally include in your local _texmf tree_. What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 7):

On a per-file basis, you would add it as a local variable, usually at the end of the document:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% LaTeX-command: "latex -shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

After you do this, `C-x C-s` to save and `C-c C-n` to reparse the document. Once you reparse the document you, `C-c C-c` will compile with the `-shell-escape` option automatically.

Every time you open the file after this, Emacs will complain about `-shell-escape` being a potentially risky variable. You can choose to apply it or not.

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122011/31416) how to make `LaTeX-command` safe as a local variable.  You should mention this works with AUCTeX.

Comment: I think it should be C-c C-n to reparse the document, instead of C-x C-n (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809587/force-auctex-to-parse-the-whole-document#comment93569045_23019517))

Comment: Good catch! [Here’s the AucTeX documentation, for reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html). I’ll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not exactly what you are asking, but you can compile it in emacs with `M-!` and then `pdflatex -shell-escape source.tex`

Answer (score 1):

This adds the -shell-escape flag to the compile-command:

`(require 'tex-mode)`
`(setcar (cdr (cddaar tex-compile-commands)) " -shell-escape ")`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `cddaar` requires `cl` (or `cl-lib`). You should mention this works with Emacs builtin TeX mode, not AUCTeX.

Answer (score 0):

From `AUCTeX`, the best option to handle the `-shell-escape` tag is to set the `TeX-command-extra-options` variable as `"-shell-escape"`

You can set it from a file variable
either at the beginning of the tex file

```
% -*- TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape" -*-
```

or at the end, using `M-x add-file-local-variable`

```
     % local variables:
     % TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
     % End:
```

You must reload your file for it to be active or evaluate  `M-:  (hack-local-variables)`

Instead, you can write a user function in your init file to toggle the shell-escape compilation on the fly:

```
     (defun toggle-shell-escape()
       "Toggle TeX-command-extra-options variable between ' ' and '-shell-escape'"
       (interactive)
       (message "TeX-command-extra-option is now %s"
                (setq TeX-command-extra-options
              (if (string-empty-p TeX-command-extra-options)
                  "-shell-escape"
                ""))))
```

and bind it to a key of your choice.

```
     (bind-key (kbd "C-c x") #'toggle-shell-escape LaTeX-mode-map)
```

`C-c x` will toggle the `-shell-escape` compilation tag.