# Can I specify an output file name/path in AUCTeX?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I know I can use <kbd>C-u C-c C-c LaTeX</kbd> to edit the command before it is run, but is there any way I can generically specify an output file name without editing the command manually?

Comment: Currently not (at least, not as far as I know), I'm already working on this feature, but it's necessary to rewrite some internal functions.

Comment: @giordano A local variable for adding command line options?

Comment: @egreg there is `LaTeX-command` but it's far from ideal, e.g., you won't be able to open output file with `C-c C-v`. My idea for future versions of AUCTeX is to define two buffer local variables, `TeX-jobname` and `TeX-output-directory`, for the name and the directory of the output file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `.emacs`.

```lisp
(put 'LaTeX-command 'safe-local-variable
     '(lambda (x)
    (stringp x)))
```

and in your LaTeX buffer issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `add-file-local-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-command` <kbd>RET</kbd> `"latex -jobname INSERTNAMEHERE -output-directory INSERTPATHHERE"` <kbd>RET</kbd> (note: `latex`, without `pdf` even if you use `pdflatex`, that is prepended when `TeX-PDF-mode` is on), but you have to add this variable in all files of the sources and you won't be able to open the output file with <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> or delete auxiliary files with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> `Clean` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Works well enough for me!  Just a note, v11.86 *does* maintain `C-c C-v` and `Clean` functionality, at least superficially.

Comment: Really? If you set a custom jobname you can open the output file with `C-c C-v`? That's really strange, `TeX-view` function opens a file with the same basename of master file. Are you sure you're opening the right PDF?

Comment: Pretty sure -- IIRC, I did a hello-world on a new file, but I could be mixing things up.  I did a lot of experimentation with TeX last night, so I'll confirm what I remember sometime today.